# Optimising MySQL queries with heavy joins

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-optimization

I currently run a site which tracks up-to-the-minute scores and ratings in a list. The list has thousands of entries that are updated frequently, and the list should be sortable by these score and ratings columns.

My SQL for getting this data currently looks like (roughly):

```
SELECT e.*, SUM(sa.amount) AS score, AVG(ra.rating) AS rating
FROM entries e 
LEFT JOIN score_adjustments sa ON sa.entry_id = e.id
    HAVING sa.created BETWEEN ... AND ... 
LEFT JOIN rating_adjustments ra ON ra.entry_id = e.id
    HAVING ra.rating > 0 
ORDER BY score 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Where the tables are (simplified):

```
entries:
    id: INT(11) PRIMARY
    ...other data...

score_adjustments:
    id: INT(11), PRIMARY
    entry_id: INT(11), INDEX, FOREIGN KEY (entries.id)
    created: DATETIME
    amount: INT(4)

rating_adjustments:
    id: INT(11), PRIMARY
    entry_id: INT(11), INDEX, FOREIGN KEY (entries.id)
    rating: DOUBLE
```

There are approx 300,000 `score_adjustments` entries and they grow at about 5,000 a day. The `rating_adjustments` is about 1/4 that.

Now, I'm no DBA expert but I'm guessing calling `SUM()` and `AVG()` all the time isn't a good thing - especially when `sa` and `ra` contain hundreds of thousands of records - right?

I already do caching on the query, but I want the query itself to be fast - yet still as up to date as possible. I was wondering if anyone could share any solutions to optimise heavy join/aggregation queries like this? I'm willing to make structural changes if necessary.

**EDIT 1**

Added more info about the query.

Comment: The actual query would help better.

Comment: A couple of indices usually do the trick, but without the table structrure, current indices, the actual query and the amount of data, it's wild guessing. After we get that all, it's just guessing.

Comment: @ypercube Added a close representation of the query

Comment: @GolezTrol I have added the table structure

Comment: @Ryall updated my answer to include an sqlfiddle with example triggers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is badly [clustered](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index).

InnoDB will store rows with "close" PKs physically close together. Since your child tables use surrogate PKs, their rows will be stored in effect randomly. When the time comes to make calculations for the given row in the "master" table, DBMS must jump all over the place to gather the related rows from the child tables.

Instead of surrogate keys, try using more "natural" keys, with the parent's PK in the leading edge, similar to this:

```
score_adjustments:
    entry_id: INT(11), FOREIGN KEY (entries.id)
    created: DATETIME
    amount: INT(4)
    PRIMARY KEY (entry_id, created)

rating_adjustments:
    entry_id: INT(11), FOREIGN KEY (entries.id)
    rating_no: INT(11)
    rating: DOUBLE
    PRIMARY KEY (entry_id, rating_no)
```

*NOTE: This assumes `created`'s resolution is fine enough and the `rating_no` was added to allow multiple ratings per `entry_id`. This is just an example - you may vary the PKs according to your needs.*

This will "force" rows belonging to the same `entry_id` to be stored physically close together, so a SUM or AVG can be calculated by just a range scan on the PK/clustering key and with very few I/Os.

Alternatively (e.g. if you are using MyISAM that doesn't support clustering), [cover](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/glossary/covering-index) the query with indexes so the child tables are not touched during querying at all.

---

On top of that, you could denormalize your design, and cache the current results in the parent table:

- Store SUM(score_adjustments.amount) as a physical field and adjust it via triggers every time a row is inserted, updated or deleted from `score_adjustments`.
- Store SUM(rating_adjustments.rating) as "S" **and** COUNT(rating_adjustments.rating) as "C". When a row is added to `rating_adjustments`, add it to S and increment C. Calculate S/C at run-time to get the average. Handle updates and deletes similarly.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll have a good read of this now and let you know what changes I make and the results.

Comment: In my case `created` is not fine enough for the score adjustments so would I just add a `score_no` (or equivalent) to the end of the PK? Also, what is the reason for not storing `AVG(rating_adjustments.rating)` directly instead of the `SUM()` and `COUNT()`?

Comment: @Ryall This way, you can easily update it just based on the current child row, without querying other rows from the child table.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense. Misread it the first time around. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you're worried about performance you could add the score and rating columns to the corresponding tables and update them on insert or update to the referenced tables using a trigger. This would cache the new results every time they are updated and you won't have to recalculate them every time, significantly reducing the amount of joining needed to get the results... just guessing but in most cases the results of your query are probably much more often fetched than updated.

Check out this sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7101/1 to see how to make the triggers and their effect, I only added triggers on insert, you can add update triggers just as easily, if you ever delete data add triggers for delete as well.

Didn't add the datetime field, if the `between ... and ...` parameters change often you might have to still do that manually every time, otherwise you can just add the between clause to the score_update trigger.

Comment: That's a great example, thanks. Had no idea SQL Fiddle existed, seems to be a handy tool!

Comment: I can assure you it doesn't just seem to be, it is, especially when talking with others, otherwise I can just do it on a local database. If this works for you please check it as the correct answer so others will know.