# mysql calculation optimization

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a column in a table that needs to hold a 'positive' and 'negative' value or 'no value'.
I have to sum millions of rows very! often and display it to users.
My question is: Which sum operation will be quicker.

1. If I mark 'no value' with 0, 'positive' with 1 and 'negative' with -1
2. If i mark 'no value' with 0, 'positive' with 1 and 'negative' with 2

My preferred option is 1. because it will save me the effort of additional php handling and will display the correct result right away.
The question is weather using a sign (-1,0,+1) in a db will slow it down or its the same as if i don't use a sign (0,1,2). Keep in mind that i will have millions of rows and they will be summed up regularly. Thank you.

Comment: In case of 2. how would you distinguish a result of `2`? It could be a single negative value or 2 positives!?!

Comment: via counts. i've just introduced 'no value' in the design so i'm trying to limit the damage it will cause performancewise. before i've user 0 and 1 for negative, positive. now i think of having 3 values and i was curious of the impact using signed int for tables with more than 10M rows.

Comment: Then I'd definitely go with option 1.

Comment: Tnx, currently its tinyint. 1 row for + vote,  1 row for - vote. i need to sum up the votes and return both the number of them and the sum of them. as i've said i have millions of rows. once a user chooses to vote for something else his previous vote is canceled by autovoting against his old vote, thus i need to keep 2 rows for each vote/unvote. this makes millions of rows. if i combine the vote/unvote in 1 row it will be smaller db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) as it will give you direct results!

No, a sign does not impact performance as long as the type for the column is defined as a signed int or real...

Your question should have been about datatype, an int is preffered, less favorable is a float and least favored a string, although mysql can sum strings the conversion will be slow.

Also, assuming this table just holds some cross reference between two other tables and an up/down vote, it would be a hell of a lot faster if you just removed all the 0 values and inserted rows only when a vote is cast. And you could make it even faster if you were caching the values and using triggers to update the cache column referenced table whenever a vote is cast/uncast.

A fiddle example to update automatically vote sums, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/044c3/1

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You are close in your edit. I need to keep rows and have either +/-/0 impact on the vote

Comment: You should go with using triggers, answered a question with triggers yesterday, let me look for it.

Comment: the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768235/optimising-mysql-queries-with-heavy-joins/12769396#12769396 and a sql fiddle to keep the score up to date on each insert http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7101/1 , you can adapt this to your vote system easily, also note that you should add triggers on update, and since you're doing very simple math you could just do something like totalvotes = totalvotes + new.vote - old.vote in the update to avoid constantly calculating the sum on millions of rows.

Comment: You could also add 2 separate columns if you need to keep upvotes and downvotes separated and update both with triggers on insert/update. Hope that helps it's a pretty simple example.

Comment: thank you again. i'll look into it closely. i have such 'cache' for my calculations. i'm not sure if it saves time. i need to do more tests. simple calculation on tinyint may be same as partial sum + query for previous result saved in 'cache' table

Comment: You should probably use a larger int if for caching if you have millions of rows though.

Comment: currently i dump the results each hour in another table (this is for multiple voting events). i have 2 options. 1. run sum on all and dump each hour for read purposes. and 2. sum the current hour votes based on time-stamps(probably slow where =time-stamp) and ad to previous hours... probably mass calculation will be faster than where'ing time-stamps on big db?!

Comment: It all depends on your database design but I think triggers are your best choice, might be smart to make a second table containing just the primary key (probably id) of the voted item and number of votes, not no cause too many rewrites to the table, it will update with each vote but updates are minor this way and generate very little traffic, still you're always up to date and you can just increment/decrement a value never needing to recalculate the sum except the initial time.

Comment: thank you. i've created a table with vote_event_id and an iterator type of column  that goes ++/-- on each vote (will make it trigger cuz its not right now) but i also need historical data on how votes changed. thats the double purpose of the 'cache' table. i keep hourly data solid and a current hour data(++/--).

Comment: the whole problem is that i keep all votes in one table and never move them. just have hourly score dumped in another table. i will add triggers and will add signed int for main votes talbe. will also test which is faster. get current votes from hourly dumps + current(timestampe-where) or just current (mass summing - last hourly...this will save the time-stamp where)

Comment: @user1698512 added a fiddle to my answer, should help you understand how to use triggers for this, it automatically creates all entries in the vote table, you just have to update them accordingly... you can use a separate table if you so wish for scores, to avoid updating timestamps, again this all happens automatically each time a vote is cast and you only have to calculate the sums once, after that you don't need to recalculate them ever again as they are always up-to-date in the totalscore column from entries table. I'll leave doing the hourly updates as an exercise for you.

Comment: @user1698512 Also for future reference, tell us what you're doing, the more information, the easier it is for us to help, I had to guess you were doing an up/down vote thingy. You can update your question so others know what you asked without reading all these comments.

Comment: You rock! thank you. i'll edit the thing question thing tomorrow and play with the fiddle. far after midnight here. Thanks!